# numpy linalg.solve, not a square matrix

Tags: python, numpy

So currently I'm working with code looking like:

```
Q,R = np.linalg.qr(matrix)
Qb = np.dot(Q.T, new_mu[b][n])
x_qr = np.linalg.solve(R, Qb)
mu.append(x_qr)
```

The code works fine as long as my matrix is square, but as soon as it's not, the system is not solvable and I got errors. If I've understood it right I can't use `linalg.solve` on non-full rank matrices, but is there a way for me to get across this obstacle without using a `lstsquare` solution?

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible, as [specified in the `np.linalg.solve` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html).

The issue is that given `Ax = b`, if `A` is not square, then your equation is either over-determined or under-determined, assuming that all rows in `A` are linearly independent. This means that there does not exist a single `x` that solves this equation.

Intuitively, the idea is that if you have `n` (length of `x`) variables that you are trying to solve for, then you need exactly `n` equations to find a unique solution for `x`, assuming that these equations are not "redundant". In this case, "redundant" means linearly dependent: one equation is equal to the linear combination of one or more of the other equations.

In this scenario, one possibly useful thing to do is to find the `x` that minimizes `norm(b - Ax)^2` (i.e. [linear least squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) solution):

```
x, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lsq(A, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

from LS Normal Equation `intercept, *coef = np.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(y)` we [can  use](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Edas01/GSACourse/Regression.pdf) equation `(X.T.dot(X)).dot(β) = (X.T).dot(y)`

```
from  scipy import linalg
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

# Generate a regression problem
X, y = make_regression(
    n_samples=50,
    n_features=2,
    n_informative=2,
    noise = 10,
    random_state=25
    )

X_b = np.column_stack((np.ones(len(y)), X)) # for intercept

########################## solve for non-square
XtX = X_b.T.dot(X_b)
XtY = X_b.T.dot(y)
x1 = np.linalg.solve(XtX, XtY);
print(x1)

########################## least-squares - compute vector x such that 2-norm is minimized
x2, sse, rank, sva = linalg.lstsq(X_b, y)
print(x2)

########### check
# euclidean distance - here shows x_solve ~ x_lstsq
print("distance between vectors: ", np.linalg.norm(x1-x2,2))
print(np.allclose(x1, x2))

## distance between vectors:   - as is tiny difference
## True

######################### check with ML
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X, y)

print(f"Intercept: {lr.intercept_}\n\
Coefficients: {lr.coef_}")
```